# Image URL is not working

Tags: c#, image, sharepoint, path

I have this piece of coding which is supposed to receive a URL as a string and this URL is supposed to be set as the Image Url :-

Heres the code

```
foreach (SPListItem item in oSpListCln)
{
    if (item.Title.Equals("Rubicks"))
    {
        Title.Text = item.Title;
        lblSyp.Text = item["Sypnosis"].ToString();
        PicPic.ImageUrl = item["PicPic"].ToString();
    }
}
```

The value of `item["PicPic"]` is `http://www.froot.nl/wp-content/uploads/quick-brown-fox-froot.jpg,http://www.froot.nl/wp-content/uploads/quick-brown-fox-froot.jpg`

This doesn't work is it cause I'm setting a string as a URL of an image cause when I hard coded the link it worked but when I set the link to a string and try, it doesn't. Does anyone know a way of how to do this?

Comment: Does the image url has an http:// in it ?, and does it reach that point to set the url ?

Comment: Is `item["PicPic"]` a valid URL?

Comment: Do the two `.Text =` lines work?

Comment: the URL has an Http:// and item[PicPic] is a URL retrieved from a webservice and convered to a string using the .tostring method.

Comment: What does the link look like when it is shown on the screen?

Comment: yeps the .Text Lines work :/ i think ill have to convert the string back to a URL but i have no clue how... :/

Comment: What do you get when you debug? Does item["PicPic"] return anything?

Comment: no errors :/ but the pic doesnt show

Comment: What is value of item["PicPic"] ? please mention it here

Comment: http://www.froot.nl/wp-content/uploads/quick-brown-fox-froot.jpg

Comment: this is the the exact text [link] (http://www.froot.nl/wp-content/uploads/quick-brown-fox-froot.jpg)

Comment: Did you already checked (with the help of breakpoints) if there is something in your variables when you run your program? And from where the call to that method is coming (callstack)? Maybe there is something wrong on another place and not just in this piece of code.

Comment: Yeps debugged it, it has the right value but it contains http://www.froot.nl/wp-content/uploads/quick-brown-fox-froot.jpg,http://www.froot.nl/wp-content/uploads/quick-brown-fox-froot.jpg

Comment: Are you working at some organisation that requires proxy authentication ?????

Comment: Edit your question. Modify what I've added to it, entering the EXACT url.

Comment: http://www.froot.nl/wp-content/uploads/quick-brown-fox-froot.jpg OR  http://www.froot.nl/wp-content/uploads/quick-brown-fox-froot.jpg,http://www.froot.nl/wp-content/uploads/quick-brown-fox-froot.jpg , which value you get when you debug it?

Comment: when i debug it the second one

Comment: To visualize the actual string when running, you could temporarily change to `lblSyp.Text = item["PicPic"].ToString();` and you should be able to see if there is anything wrong with the URL

Comment: Okay the issue is im reading the URL off a SharePoint list and that field has been sending me the url and the alternate URL so i had been getting the URL string as "http://www.froot.nl/wp-content/uploads/quick-brown-fox-froot.jpg,http://www.froot.nl/wp-content/uploads/quick-brown-fox-froot.jpg", i need a way to extract only the URl in the String. How do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the returned string is comma-separated as you wrote in comments, you could do something like:

```
string[] urlParts = item["PicPic"].ToString().Split(',');
PicPic.ImageUrl = urlParts[0];
```